# What makes a good chalkboard?

Tags: teaching

I've encountered lots of chalkboards through my career, and they vary widely in quality.  Some write smoothly and erase cleanly; for others, the chalk squeaks and the eraser just smears.

I assume there are differences in the materials they use, the construction techniques, how the surface is prepared or treated, and so on.  But I'm clueless as to what these differences might be, and how they affect the quality.  If I'm looking for a "good" one, what questions should I ask?

(Academics are one of the few groups these days that use chalkboards on a regular basis, so I hope this question is suitable for this site.  Please note that I'm not asking for specific product recommendations, just general information.)

Comment: In my opinion: the best chalkboard is a whiteboard!

Comment: @F'x: Should we step outside to settle this? ;-)  Actually, I could ask the very same question about whiteboards.

Comment: In my opinion: The best whiteboard is a chalkboard!

Comment: The contrast on whiteboards can be too high, so I prefer a chalkboard as well. Furthermore, ink is shiny as it goes on, and makes viewing at wide angles difficult. Not to mention turning off the lights at the front of the room to use the projector simultaneously with the whiteboard.

Comment: Remember: no chalkboard can be good without good chalk!

Comment: @F'x:  Have you ever tried writing on a whiteboard in chalk?

Comment: There was a question [What's so great about blackboards?](http://mathoverflow.net/q/5936/10833) on mathoverflow.

Comment: "If I'm looking for a good one, what questions should I ask?" Hmmm... Why don't you just *try* it? If you can write and dry-erase without trouble 10 times using both white and color chalk, it should last forever. If not, it won't work regardless of anything else. Just bring some nasty chalk for experiments (especially the color one).

Comment: @fedja: That would certainly be ideal.  Unfortunately procurement contracts sometimes mean we have to buy stuff like this sight unseen.

Comment: I am a homeschool mom looking for the same thing. Has anyone found a good supplier? I want just one.

Comment: I my experience (long ago by now, chalkboards have all been replaced by whiteboards, except in one classroom) the quality of the board is relevant, but what is absolutely critical is the quality of the chalk.

Comment: For cleaning: some boards are to be cleaned using a wet towel (not a dry whatever). For chalk compatibility: some boards work better with the very hard chalks, some with the softer ones.

Answer (score 15):

The good chalkboards appear to be made of porcelain enamel fused to a steel core. See [this site](http://www.madehow.com/Volume-2/Chalkboard.html) for more details on the manufacturing process. As JeffE mentioned in a comment on another answer, cheaper chalkboards are made by painting wood or chipboard with a special chalkboard paint. Although these are good for crafts, they are NOT the kind you want to have in a classroom. They [have to be primed with chalk](http://www.ellaclaireinspired.com/2013/01/chalkboard-maintenance-101.html) before the first use and after being cleaned with a damp cloth. Also they will often have to be given another coat of paint after being used for a while.

For non-squeak writing, break long pieces of chalk in half--this will **usually** take care of the problem! I have noticed that regular, i.e. daily, sponging with an all-purpose cleaning solution also helps to prevent smearing while writing/erasing.

Comment: Are these chalk boards made of porcelain enamel cheaper as compared to wooden chalkboard? Can schools and other educational institutions be able to afford it?

Comment: Although I don't know exactly what the price range would be for the porcelain enamel versus the wooden chalkboards, the wooden boards are usually cheaper--and they act like it! Can schools afford porcelain enamel? I guess that depends on just how limited your budget is, but they shouldn't be prohibitively expensive. They might be hard to find, though. Whiteboards are taking over...

Answer (score 6):

Just a partial answer, since I am not discussing materials and building techniques but only giving a couple of tips.

Chalk squeaking should depend on its length; break it into two parts to avoid it. Not sure if this has been studied rigorously, but it seems to work in my experience.

As for erasing, I am personally a fan of using a damp towel rather than dry-erasing. It takes some more work and preparation, but the results are much better.

Comment: Doesn't damp erasing remove the dry foundation of chalk, and thus require the board be re-finished with chalk?

Comment: Some cheaper chalkboards are really just painted wood (or chipboard); erasing these with water is a *bad* idea.  Good chalkboards don't have this problem.

Comment: So are good boards made of slate or something similar? I suppose I've never used a good board.

Answer (score 6):

The best chalkboard, if you can afford it, is slate. It is the combination of grain consistency and durability that allows the consistent accretion of chalk on the surface of the board. The only reason it is not used is that it is prohibitively expensive and either heavy or fragile, depending on the depth of the slate. I suppose this could be improved with a non-flexible backing.

Comment: Certainly the best chalkboards I've ever used have been slate. Dark background, high contrast (even with colored chalks), reliable surface and good erasing. Now if only I didn't end up with chalk dust all over everything. But they are expensive.

Comment: @dmckee Do you have any brands?

Comment: @AlJebr No. I'd search for blackboards and then read to find out who can actually deliver slate. Or the porcelain mentioned above though I have never used those.