# Is there a specific brand of chalkboards used in colleges? What is your favorite brand?

Tags: mathematics, teaching, independent-study

I'm a mathematics student looking to invest in a good chalkboard for my room. I currently have a cheap Quartet but I find it is not very good compared to chalkboards at my school. It is not very smooth and doesn't erase cleanly. I have even purchased the porcelain Quartet and found it still is not very good.

At my school, I have seen a swivel Marsh industries board and it is really smooth, erases very cleanly. However, I do not know what brand is used on the walls of the classrooms.

**Is there a specific brand of chalkboards used in colleges? What is your favorite brand?**

Comment: There is a very similar question at [What makes a good chalkboard](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/12578/62311).

Comment: It seems chalkboards are on the way out.  Nowadays we have whiteboards or even some computer-controlled screen taking its place.  Chalk dust is bad for computers anyway...

Comment: Something I didn't mention before but might be of use to you. The slate boards that I used on one of my jobs were installed in the brand-new, super-spiffy building built for the physics department at a large public university in a plains state just four years after sputnik was put into orbit. There are non-trivial odds that the company that built them is long gone, or even if it exists that they don't have a record of the sale or even know the exact specs of the boards.